# Brown bits/discoloration on Aloe Vera plant

Tags: aloe

My Aloe Vera plant has some brown discoloration l, I've just re potted in a bigger pot. Is there anything else I can do to make it better? Some of the ends look a bit skinny and dry too! 
[image: discoloration][image: dry end]

Comment: Was it like this before you repotted it? It looks like it's got potting soil on it. If it's not potting soil it might be "rust" which you can treat with sulphur.

Comment: To better answer this questions a few details are needed:how long had you had the plant before you re-potted it? What conditions was it growing in (sunny, shady, wet, dry, plastic pot, clay pot)? What made you decide to re-pot vs. trimming of leaves. I agree it is stressed most likely do to fungus. the question is Was it stable growing in the other pot or was it wobbling in the pot? Did it smell when you re-potted the plant or were the roots discolored or mushy. Treatments like fungicides can help but sometimes you have to find out if there is a problem behavior to help with treatment.

Answer (score 1):

It is thrips, they’re really hard to see.

https://getbusygardening.com/control-thrips-on-houseplants/

Comment: Welcome! A few points to make this a better answer: a) What makes you think it’s thrips? What are the telltale signs, future readers may need to watch out for? b) That link may be seen as spam attempt. Are you affiliated with the site?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34596)